# Pulling Hardware Serial Number via Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, vb6, hardware

I am writing an application in Visual Basic that pulls basic information about the computer and outputs the data onto a form. Currently, I am trying to pull the serial number for the machine I would be using. For example, pulling a serial number of a laptop from the BIOS. I have looked around the internet and haven't really found how to do this in Visual Basic without using WMI or C. Is there a way to do this in Visual Basic?

Below is what I have currently in the form, so you can get an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
        TextBoxComputerName.Text = Environment.MachineName
        TextBoxOSVersion.Text = System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString
        TextBoxOSFullName.Text = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
        TextBoxCurrentUser.Text = System.Environment.UserName
        TextBox64Bit.Text = System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
        TextBoxSystemDirectory.Text = System.Environment.SystemDirectory
        TextBoxDomain.Text = System.Environment.UserDomainName
        ' CHECK SERIAL NUMBER HERE.
```

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Any reason to not use WMI for this kind of information?

Comment: You will need to use WMI, use the [`WMI Code Creator`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) from Microsoft to explore.

Comment: Doesn't WMI require to have the WMI library installed on the machine you are using it on? If that is the case, then I can't really use that as a solution because I need to use this application on multiple machines.

Comment: You will just need to include the `System.Management` Namespace.  WMI is built into Windows.

Comment: When I do "Imports System.Management", I get the error from Visual Studio saying "Type 'ManagementObject' is not defined."

Comment: no ONE answer will work for VB.NET, VBA and VB6 they are VERY different from each other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work for you just great! First add reference to System.Management and then make sure to import it at the top of your class as well. I did this on a form load event, but you can put it anywhere...

```
  Imports System.Management

  Dim q As New SelectQuery("Win32_bios")
  Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(q)
  Dim info As New ManagementObject

  For Each info In search.Get
    MessageBox.Show("Serial Number: " & info("serialnumber").ToString & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Bios Version: " & info("version").ToString)
  Next
```

You can declare a string first if you would like and then set it to: info("serialnumber").ToString and the set that to you txtSerial.Text = your declared string

Here is what I get...

[image: My outcome]

Comment: Thanks for this, and I am glad to see it worked for you. But, I am using Visual Studio, and when I put that code in, I get all types of errors. One of them being for "Imports System.Management", it gives me the error "Type 'ManagementObject' is not defined.".

Comment: Did you ADD REFERENCE? You have to, not just the import. It is in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I added the reference for System.Management which removed all of the errors except one, which says that "Imports System.Management" is a syntax error. Granted, I am using VB(VBA) not VB.NET (if that makes a difference). Thank you so much!

Comment: You tagged VB.NET . . . If this helped you don't forget to accept.

Comment: no ones mentioned it, but you need to add a reference not only to "System.Management" but ALSO to "System.Management.Instrumentation"

Answer (score 1):

This is VBScript but should be pastable into VB6.

You do know this field is blank on many computers?

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_BIOS")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.SerialNumber
Next
```

From a command prompt (but I don't think home editions get the console program wmic)

```
wmic bios get /format:list
```

or

```
wmic bios get serialnumber /format:list
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Treek's Licecnsing Library. It has class for generating hardware serial.

http://msdn.treekslicensinglibrary.com/html/f2bfa10c-d5d9-25ac-39c2-46e2393c0fbe.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that will return:
*)  Computer Name
*)  Assembly Name
*)  Login User Name
*)  Serial No

Imports System.Management

''' 
''' Provides the Methods and Properties to retrieve and make available to the
''' Application the:
'''     *)  Computer Name
'''     *)  Assembly Name
'''     *)  Login User Name
'''     *)  PC Serial Number
'''
''' 
Public Class clsGetComputerInformation
Private ReadOnly mstrClsTitle As String = "clsGetComputerInformation"

```
Public ReadOnly Property pstrComputerName() As String
    Get
        Return Environment.MachineName
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property pstrUserName() As String
    Get
        Return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property pstrAssemblyName() As String
    Get
        Return My.Application.Info.AssemblyName
    End Get
End Property


Public Function pstrSystemSerialNumber() As String
    Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_bios")
    Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
    Dim info As ManagementObject
    Dim lstrSerialNo As String = ""

    For Each info In search.Get()
        lstrSerialNo = info("SerialNumber").ToString()
    Next
    Return lstrSerialNo
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get to this a bit backwards in VBA, using the `FileSystemObject`.  You will need to set a reference to the Windows Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetHDSerial()

    Dim objFSO          As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder       As Folder

    Dim strComputer     As String

    strComputer = "myComputer"
    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\" & strComputer & "\c$")
    Debug.Print Hex(objFolder.Drive.SerialNumber)

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

This does not account for multiple physical drives, which wasn't a problem in my environment.

Comment: how might i accomplish this in ms excel using late binding?